# In Yii, how can I call views belonging to another models that has a HAS_MANY relation defined with the current controller's model?

Tags: php, templates, yii, yii-cactiverecord

I need some guidance on how to call views within a controller for models that have a relationship defined with the current controller"s model.

In my case, I have a model names "catalog", which has a HAS_MANY relationship with another model called "items".
In the "view" view for my "catalog" model, I would like to display an ajax form to let user add "items" to the current "catalog" and also I want to render the current "catalog" model"s items.

In theory, I should have a distinct 'item' controller who should take care of rendering a single 'item' view and creation form.

The issue is that thanks to the relation defined in my 'catalog' model, I am loading all the catalog's items at the same time as when I load a 'catalog' model.
But since I also want to be able to independently create 'items' for the current 'catalog' without updating the whole catalog model, I want to render in my 'catalog' view a 'item' create form.
I also need to have an independent 'item' view action so that I can render via AJAX newly created 'item' without rendering the whole 'catalog' again.

I'm thinking that in my 'catalog' 'view' view, I should loop through the $catalog->items and for each do a renderPartial of the 'item' 'view' view.

But I have read that using views from another controller within a given controller is an absolute no no.
Same thing for rendering the 'item' create form, which belongs to the 'item' controller, but that I want to render within my 'catalog' 'view' view.

Is it acceptable to make an exception for this case? 
This is what I'm currently doing, in my 'catalog' 'view' view:

```
foreach($catalog->items as $item):
  $this->renderPartial('/item/_view', array ( 'item' => $item ) , FALSE, FALSE );
```

Let me know if there is a better design pattern that I should be adhering to?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Lothaire

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I didn't undestand you completely but why you don't use many instances of `CActiveForm` widget for `Item` model?

In **view** file:

```
    foreach($catalog->items as $item)
    {
        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
           'id'=>"catalog-form-{$item->id}",
           'action'=>"/ajax/item/update/",
           'enableClientValidation'=>true,
           'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
           ),
        )
        echo CHtml::hiddenField('itemID', $item->id)
        //...
        $this->endWidget();
   );
```

And then in `/ajax/item/update/` you can do everything you want, including DAO instead of AR. There's no especial need to keep relations btw models in the controller for any call from this form.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Thanks for your response. I have read about widgets but I am not sure why it would be advantageous to use in my case. I am in fact using a `CActiveForm` but it's in the `_form.php` partial view of my `Item` controller. It seems to me like it is better to keep all the actions and related views for `Item` within my `ItemController` rather than create a standalone form for `Item` as a widget. Indeed, in my example, I want to render the `Item` create form within my catalog view, but I might also want to render this form in an `Item` view.

Comment: The only weird thing about my approach is that I end up calling the `Item` `_from.php` view in the context of the `view` action of my `catalog` controller.

Comment: PartialView isn't an instrument to clone forms. Logically any of Item's instances relate to the only controller, and it processes them equivalently. You can call any controller from any form. .. I feel I don't understand your problem completely. There's no problem :)